# How do I get 'ssconvert' to embed off-sheet references?

Tags: export-to-excel, xls, import-from-csv, gnumeric, ssconvert

I have this working, using Gnumeric's `ssconvert`:

```
ssconvert --merge-to=merged.xls test1.csv test2.csv test3.csv
```

It happily imports formulae, such as `=MIN(G2:G4)` correctly.

The problem I have is with off-sheet references.

How do I, with the above setup, get a cross-sheet reference to work?

For example, in `test3.csv`:

```
=('test1.csv'.G11+'test1.csv'.G8)
```

When I try this, if converts the off-sheet references to text. I have tried doing this with LibreOffice Calc and OS X Numbers - I even tried the Numbers reference format:

```
test1.csv::Table 1::G8
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks as if this might be impossible. Unfortunately. If anybody has any suggestions, even partial ones, not a whole solution, I'd still be interested to hear!